# Prevent library user from overriding my function

Tags: c, dynamic-linking

I have create dynamic library in which I define a function. I use this function internally in my own library and dont expose via headers. But if user of my library defines similar function then that function overrides my function and breaks my lib.

Here is an example:

libmylib.so:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void hello() {
    puts("hello form t.c");
}

void hello1() {
    hello();
}
```

a.out:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void hello1();

void hello() {
    puts("hello from main.c");
}

int main() {
    hello();
    hello1();
}
```

Output I get:

```
hello from main.c
hello from main.c
```

Comment: Maybe declaring `static void hello()` in libmylib.so is an option.

Comment: Use unique name for your library functions. `void hello1_hello_xvtYuknl() `

Comment: I think you can't prevent this with dynamic lib , however use static lib can prevent your issue.. or specify function prototype in a header like "your_lib.h" and add built option (-Wall -Werror) to notice user about redefine a function in your lib.

Comment: If you don't mind that your library contains just one module, you can link all its modules in such a single one before building the library. This should resolve all references to your internal function.

Comment: Most dynamic library formats support control over visibility of external symbols via compiler and/or linker options - for example, GCC's [visibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) support.

Comment: Use extensions `.h` or `.c` and never anything else. It isn't clear how you intend to use this `libmylib.so`, is it a .c file added to the linker or is it a header?

Answer (score 2):

If function is local to a single a file just make it `static`. Otherwise you can hide it via

```
__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
void hello() {
    puts("hello from main.c");
}
```

Actually the recommended approach is to hide all functions by default (by adding `-fvisibility=hidden` to `CFLAGS`) and only export functions that you need via `__attribute__((visibility("default")))`.